# Sort messages in Realtime DB by timestamp

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I am having trouble by getting my messages stored in realtime db in order.

Here's my db structure

```
messages: {
  $chatId: {
     $messageId: {
       timestamp: 1664884736728,
       sender:"36a72WVw4weQEoXfk3T9gCtOL9n2",
       message: "Hello world"
     }
  }
}
```

This is my chat repository

```
  //get all messages of a chat
  Query getMessages(String chatId) {
    //get all messages of a chat
    final messages = _database.ref().child("messages/$chatId");
    //return all messages of a chat
    return messages;
  }
}
```

and this is how I am displaying it

```
StreamBuilder(
                stream: _chatRepository.getMessages(chatId).onValue,
                builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.data != null &&
                      snapshot.data?.snapshot?.value != null &&
                      snapshot.hasData) {
                    final messages = Map.from(snapshot.data?.snapshot.value as Map);
                    return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: messages.length,
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        final currChat = messages.values.toList()[index];
                        return BubbleCustom(...),
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  }
                  return Container();
                },
              ),
```

This is my index in realTimeDB

```
{
  "rules": {
    "messages": {
      "$chatId": {
        ".indexOn": ["timestamp"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I need to get them in timestamp order. Is there any way I can do this? I hope you can help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by doing it in the frontend like this:

```
  final messages = Map.from(snapshot.data?.snapshot.value as Map);
                  //sort messages by timestamp ascending order
                  final messagesList = messages.values.toList();
                  messagesList.sort((a, b) => a["timestamp"].compareTo(b["timestamp"]));
                  final newMessagelist = List.from(messagesList.reversed);
   return ListView.builder(
                    physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                    reverse: true,
                    itemCount: newMessagelist.length,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      final currChat = newMessagelist[index];
                      return BubbleCustom(
                        text: currChat["message"],
                        isSender: currChat["sender"] == senderUser.id,
                        tail: true,
                        textStyle: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16,
                          color: currChat["sender"] == senderUser.id ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  );
```

with `reverse: true` and inverting the list before I render it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `orderByChild` to get the messages in the order of a specific child. So there that'd be:

```
stream: _chatRepository.getMessages(chatId).orderByChild('timestamp').onValue
```

Don't forget to [define an index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data) for `timestamp`, so that the sorting can be done on the database server.

To learn more on this, see the Firebase documentation on [sorting and filtering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/flutter/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is my current index and it is not working  .```"messages":{".indexOn": ["timestamp"]}```

Comment: The index needs to be defined on the place where you run the query, so in your case that'd be in `$chatId`.

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, but this is still not working. I updated my question with my new index

Comment: "is still not working" is really hard to help with. Does the change I propose in my answer make sense after reading the links I provided? Does that also explain why your original approach can't have worked, and how the approach I describe would address that? --- If so, debug your new problem which is now in the new approach. My first step would be to set a breakpoint in the builder and run in the debugger. Does that hit the breakpoint? If so, step though the code line by line and check the value of each variable. After this, what's the first line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?